# How to solve opp_msgc issue in omnet++?

Tags: omnet++

I wrote a message and saved it as **xyz.msg** file. I read it somewhere that building the project will generate **_m.cc** and **_m.h** files, but no such files were generated. I tried it through console too, but it says:

> opp_msgc no such internal/external command"

(despite of the fact that environment variable "PATH" is set to omnet++ bin directory).

So, I checked **omnet++**'s bin folder and saw that for **opp_msgc** there was no **.cmd** file.

Please guide me for how to generate **_m.h** and **_m.cc**.
Earliest will be the best. Thank you.

Comment: Which OS do you use? How do you start OMNeT++? Could you show structures of files of your project (i.e. directories and files)?

Comment: Did you use mingwenv.cmd to run OMNeT++ and to run the console?

Comment: @JerzyD.:  I am using Win 8.1. I tried to build the project both ways, by running OMNeT++ from the desktop as well as from mingwenv.cmd. And in the console that was invoked from mingwenv.cmd, same error "opp_msgc is not recognized as an internal/external command" is displayed.

Directory structure:-
/Project1
     /src
          /modules
               /messages
                     /xyz.msg
I hope this is what your were asking for.

Comment: @Christoph Sommer: I tried to build the project both ways, by running OMNeT++ from the desktop as well as from mingwenv.cmd. And in the console that was invoked from mingwenv.cmd, same error "opp_msgc is not recognized as an internal/external command" is displayed.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding OMNeT++?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Still the problem is persistent.

Comment: The _m.h and _m.cc files got generated.
I rebuild OMNeT++, started it from mingwenv.cmd and closed all the projects on which my project was dependent. And the built my project. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows one **has to** start `OMNeT++` from `mingwenv.cmd`.
I suppose that in your project `messages` subdirectory is not marked as source location. The simplest way to correct it is to move subdirectory `messages` into `src`.

Comment: I was able to generate _m.cc and _m.h without transferring "messages" folder. I think rebuilding OMNeT++ and starting it from mingwenv.cmd does the work. Thanks for helping. :)